# Unable to read table from application as well from ms sql client when apply @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED) on service layer jpa

Tags: sql-server, spring, hibernate, jpa

We are using Spring , Hibernate and JPA in application side and MS SQL Server as database and JBOSS 6.4.0 as Application Server.

There are two different services in the application. One service inserts/updates data in some database tables using @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED) and the other service is reading data from same database tables using @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.SUPPORTS). Problem - When the first service is running , second service is not able to read the data from those DB tables. It appears that the DB tables gets locked as we are not able to access those tables even from SQL Server Client. Service here refers to Spring Service Classes. We don not have a situation where both the services can concurrently write data in DB tables. So the aim is to be able to read the data from tables using service 2 while service 1 is inserting/updating data in tables.

Service 1 - Cron Job Service layer

Service 2 - UI service Layer

Below is the configuration.

applicationContext.xml

```
<!-- JPA EntityManagerFactory Setup Begin -->
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
            class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <!-- <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="myPersistenceUnit" /> -->
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.XXX.ccp.dao" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
        </property>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">validate</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        <!-- <property name="persistenceProvider">
            <bean class="org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider" />
        </property> -->
    </bean>
    <!-- JPA EntityManagerFactory Setup End -->


    <!-- JPA TransactionManager Setup End -->
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>
    <tx:annotation-driven />
    <!-- JPA TransactionManager Setup End -->

    <bean id="persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"
        class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />
```

persistance.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>    
    <persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
             http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
             version="2.1">

    <persistence-unit name="CCP" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <!-- <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider> -->
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <non-jta-data-source>java:/jdbc/ManufacturerDbDs</non-jta-data-source>
        <!--exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes-->
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

Cron Job Service Layer->

```
@Service("myService1")
public class MyService1Impl implements MyService1{
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor = CCPDaoException.class, readOnly = false)
    public String doStatusSynch() throws RemoteException {
    //code goes here
}
}
```

UI service layer ->

```
 @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.SUPPORTS, readOnly=true)
        public List<DeviceDataSynchDTO> getAllCarrierAndDbSynchStatus()  throws CCPDaoException{//code goes here}
```

To run queries in JPA, we are using below persistanceContext 
private EntityManager entityManager;

Please let me know if I need to provide further details on this.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I did not get any solution for this. workaround - I have moved @Transctional to Dao layer to get rid of this problem. By narrowing the transaction, I am able to read data from the same table.

Answer (score 0):

Please provide some code, my best guess is that the first transaction is not committing (i.e. the method which is annotated @Transaction has not completed), when the read method is called.

The read only method can be annotated

```
@Transactional(readOnly=true)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I have already applied readOnly="true". Please let me know what part of code u want me to share?

Comment: Any lock will be released when the write transaction finishes.  The read transaction will not be able to see what is in the write transaction until it has finished.  I think the key to this is making sure that write has finished before the read.  Remember the transaction annotation will not take effect on a mineral method call.

Answer (score 0):

I am not too familiar with MSSql. What I am suspecting is entire table is getting locked instead of row. By default, it's a **row-level** lock. When a session/transaction exceeds approx. 5000 **row-level** locks, the lock is escalated to **table-level** lock (or partition-level, if you have partitioned tables). You may have to control your service 1 (cron job), if it is inserting/updating bulk amount of records continuously in a single transaction.

Ref [default-sql-server-2008-locking-behaviour](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/9177/default-sql-server-2008-locking-behaviour)